# Как автоматически вызывать обрыв ftp-соединения?

Tags: linux, shell, ftp, функциональное-тестирование

Скрипт на python в ходе работы скачивает файлы с ftp-сервера.

Процесс использует боевой ftp, и я не хотел бы усложнять процесс поднятием виртуалки с тестовым ftp - работа скрипта чувствительна к содержимому и мне придется настраивать обновление данных.

Нужно протестировать поведение при обрыве соединения *в процессе скачивания*. Желательно делать это автоматически, то есть вручную делать `kill myftpserver` или выдергивание шнура из сетевой карты — не вариант.

Таким образом, мне нужно либо обрывать текущее соединение прямо на тестовом сервере, либо поднимать прокси, на нем ждать соединения и обрывать через секунду-другую. Не представляю, как это реализовать. Нужно хотя бы название утилиты или команды, которой я смогу отловить текущее соединение и оборвать его, либо блокировать все текущие соединения на заданный ip.

Разумеется, тестирую я на тестовом инстансе. К нему есть root-доступ по ssh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Думаю проще всего делать это с помощью iptables. Просто запрещать передавать пакеты, можно попробовать действия `REJECT` для быстрого обрыва или `DROP` для слета по таймауту.

Простейшее правило (если задается на машине где тестируемая прога) типа `iptables -I OUTPUT -d ip-ftp-сервера -j REJECT`
Добавлять можно простеньким скриптом на shell периодически делая задержки sleep, например.

Или усложнить само правило и задействовать например `connbytes`.

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -d ip-ftp-сервера -m \
    connbytes --connbytes 10000 --connbytes-dir both \
    --connbytes-mode bytes -j REJECT
```

должно оборвать соединение после прокачки по нему 10 килобайт.

Если с iptables до этого не работали ... `iptables -I` добавляет правило. `iptables -D` с точно такими же параметрами, как были при добавлении - удаляет. `iptables -L -nv` покажет существующие правила

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал сейчас. Без connbytes работает, а вот с этим параметром выдает следующее. (`sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -d 1.2.3.4 -m connbytes --connbytes 10000 -j REJECT`) `iptables v1.4.21: connbytes: option "--connbytes-dir" must be specified`. Про `--connbytes` и `--connbytes-dir` ничего не нахожу в справке.

Comment: @NickVolynkin `iptables -m connbytes -h` выдаст в конце справки несколько строк по этому модулю. Судя по описанию `--connbytes-dir [original, reply, both]` это какой трафик учитывать исходящий, входящий или суммарный. Попробуйте `--connbytes-dir reply`, большим будет трафик от сервера, ну или both для надежности

Comment: @NickVolynkin еще потом попробуйте вместо `REJECT` использовать `DROP`. для тестов поведения программы полезно. Первое сообщает отправителю пакета об ошибке сразу и соединение рвется. А второе просто выбрасывает пакет молча, в итоге соединение порвется только по таймауту, прикинете время сколько она будет в подвисшем состоянии

Comment: действительно, был необходимы ещё два параметра. Добавил в ответ вариант, который в итоге сработал. Про `REJECT` и `DROP` отличная идея, спасибо, сейчас проверю.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не по теме вопроса, но все же дополню. `iptables` умеет еще и ухудшать качество соединения: ограничивать скорость, создавать лаги, дропать случайные пакеты, переставлять их и дублировать... Можно и в таком режиме тоже проверить.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я то же думал об этом, но для tcp соединений это не особенно актуально, все потери и дубли возьмет на себя ядро ОС, для программы да - будут тормоза и возможно обрывы соединений, если Ip-стек не справится с ситуацией. Вот для приложений использующих UDP это были бы полезные тесты

Comment: @Mike, там могут в самых неожиданных местах посыпаться тайм-ауты...

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо, очень ценная информация.